# Apple Mach-O Linker Error '-websockets'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I just started doing another tutorial from the ray wenderlich site and I got this error as soon as i started the new project. I'm currently using a cocos2dx 2.1.4 template for the tutorial and i definitely made the mistake of updating my xcode to the latest version. Again I haven't even started writing any code but heres my error.

http://i.imgur.com/lzCo8Xe.png?1

Thank you for any help in advance, I just want to get back to learning

Comment: It looks like you inadvertently edited your linker flags - it should be `-lwebsockets`.

Comment: what file or tab can I go into that will allow me to edit that?

Comment: Select the target and then scroll down to the `Linking` section.

Comment: THANK YOU! You literally saved my soul. You're the man dude thanks again.